# How to separate values in a dictionary to be put into CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write my JSON output to CSV, but I'm not sure how to separate my values into individual columns

This is my current code

```
with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

for key, value in response.json().items():
   writer.writerow([value])
print(value)
```

This is the csv file I am getting:
[current csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwyNu.png)

This is the desired csv file/output I want to get:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31KLr.png)

This is an example of my JSON Output

```
[{'id': '123', 'custom_id': '12', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 'Sunshine'}, {'id': '224', 'custom_id': '14', 'company': 38, 'company_name': 'Flowers'}, 
{'id': '888', 'custom_id': '10', 'company': 99, 'company_name': 'Fields'}]
```

how about this JSON format? (a more complicated one)

```
    [{'id': '777', 'custom_id': '000112', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 
   'Weddings Inc', 'delivery_address': '25 olive park terrace, 61234', 'delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'sender_name': 'Joline', 'sender_email': '', 'sender_contact': '91234567', 'removed': None, 'recipient_name': 'Joline', 'recipient_contact': '91866655', 'notes': '', 'items': [{'id': 21668, 'name': 'Loose hair flowers', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21667, 'name': "Groom's Boutonniere", 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21666, 'name': 'Bridal Bouquet', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}], 'latitude': '1.1234550920764211111', 'longitude': '103.864352476201000000', 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.385467Z', 'updated': '2019-08-15T05:41:27.930110Z', 'status': 'pending', 'verbose_status': 'Pending', 'logs': [{'id': 56363, 'order': '50c402', 'order_custom_id': '000112', 'order_delivery_address': '25 olive park terrace, 61234', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order was created.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.431790Z', 'removed': None}, {'id': 56364, 'order': '50c402d8-7c76-45b5-b883-e2fb887a507e', 'order_custom_id': 'INV-000112', 'order_delivery_address': '25 olive park terrace, 61234', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order is pending.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.433139Z', 'removed': None}], 'reschedule_requests': [], 'signature': None}, 


{'id': '241', 'custom_id': '000123', 'company': 22, 'company_name': 'Pearl Pte Ltd', 'delivery_address': '90 Merchant Road, Hotel Royal, 223344', 'delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-11-29T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-11-29T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'sender_name': 'Vera Smith', 'sender_email': '', 'sender_contact': '81234567', 'removed': None, 'recipient_name': 'Vera Smith', 'recipient_contact': '81234561', 'notes': '', 'items': [{'id': 22975, 'name': 'Custom wrapped bouquet', 'quantity': 2, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 22974, 'name': "Parents' boutonniere x 3", 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 22973, 'name': "Groom's boutonniere", 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 22972, 'name': 'Loose hair flowers', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 22971, 'name': 'Bridal Bouquet', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}], 'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 'created': '2019-08-30T03:20:17.477528Z', 'updated': '2019-08-30T03:29:25.307856Z', 'status': 'pending', 'verbose_status': 'Pending', 'logs': [{'id': 59847, 'order': '24117085-9104-4442-841b-4a734f801d39', 'order_custom_id': 'INV-000123', 'order_delivery_address': '90 Merchant Road, Hotel Royal, 223344', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-11-29T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-11-29T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order was created.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-30T03:20:17.511250Z', 'removed': None}, {'id': 59848, 'order': '24117085-9104-4442-841b-4a734f801d39', 'order_custom_id': 'INV-000123', 'order_delivery_address': '90 Merchant Road, Hotel Royal, 223344', 'order_delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-11-29T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-11-29T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 'message': 'Order is pending.', 'failure_reason': None, 'success_code': None, 'success_description': None, 'created': '2019-08-30T03:20:17.513132Z', 'removed': None}], 'reschedule_requests': [], 'signature': None}]
```

Comment: Can you add the Json example also?

Comment: Could you post a sample dict file that I could test on before posting the answer?

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero this is JSON example 


[{'id': '123', 'custom_id': '12', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 'Sunshine'}, {'id': '224', 'custom_id': '14', 'company': 38, 'company_name': 'Flowers'}, {'id': '888', 'custom_id': '10', 'company': 99, 'company_name': 'Fields'}]

Comment: @TarunKolla this is the sample dict in JSON format 

[{'id': '123', 'custom_id': '12', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 'Sunshine'}, {'id': '224', 'custom_id': '14', 'company': 38, 'company_name': 'Flowers'}, {'id': '888', 'custom_id': '10', 'company': 99, 'company_name': 'Fields'}]

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import csv

csv_file = 'my_file.csv'
csv_columns = ['id', 'custom_id', 'company', 'company_name']
dict_data = [{'id': '123', 'custom_id': '12', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 'Sunshine'}, {'id': '224', 'custom_id': '14', 'company': 38, 'company_name': 'Flowers'}, {'id': '888', 'custom_id': '10', 'company': 99, 'company_name': 'Fields'}]

try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Comment: `csv_columns = dict_data[0].keys()` this works too based on how you would like to use the code.

Comment: thanks, that works, but what about a more complicated JSON where the list contains different variables, hence the code above won't be able to cater to it, (i added the more complicated JSON in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` library:

- [`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) - Write object to a comma-separated values (csv) file.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'id': '123', 'custom_id': '12', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 'Sunshine'},
 {'id': '224', 'custom_id': '14', 'company': 38, 'company_name': 'Flowers'},
{'id': '888', 'custom_id': '10', 'company': 99, 'company_name': 'Fields'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('sample.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your response data in `json` format

```
response =  [{'id': '123', 'custom_id': '12', 'company': 28, 'company_name': 'Sunshine'}, 
            {'id': '224', 'custom_id': '14', 'company': 38, 'company_name': 'Flowers'}, 
            {'id': '888', 'custom_id': '10', 'company': 99, 'company_name': 'Fields'}]
```

You can convert it to a list of lists using

```
header = [response[0].keys()]
data = [row.values() for row in response]
csv_list = header + data
```

And then save it to `csv` using

```
with open('dict.csv', "w") as f:
    for row in csv_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % ','.join(str(col) for col in row))
```

This should yield your desired output